# SmartGWT 5 Maven Dependency,

Tags: maven, smartgwt

Per a previous question on here, I was able to run:

```
mvn com.isomorphic:isc-maven-plugin:1.1.1:install -Dproduct=SMARTGWT -Dlicense=LGPL -DbuildNumber=5.0p -DbuildDate=2014-11-30
```

This did work.  But I wonder ... do we need to do this again for the latest build?  How do we even know where to find the latest build.   I just want to use the latest, stable version, and not a nightly build.

Also, what is the correct dependency for SmartGWT 5.0p in my pom.xml file?
I have the old version which worked with 4.0, or do I need to use a new dependency?   Is there anything else I might need to add to my pom.xml file?

Believe I hit Google for the last two days, and even on the SmartGWT Isomorphic site I still couldn't find a definitive answer.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Due to Isomorphic licence scheme unfortunately if you need to update to a newer smartgwt build you cannot rely on maven "by design" features. You should run the install command again changing buildNumber or/and buildDate as desired.

Example

```
mvn com.isomorphic:isc-maven-plugin:1.1.1:install -Dproduct=SMARTGWT -Dlicense=LGPL -DbuildNumber=5.1p -DbuildDate=2016-01-07
```

The dependencies in your pom file should then use:

```
   <version>5.1p-20160107</version>
```

where `5.1p` corresponds to the `buildNumber` value and `20160107` to the `buildDate`.

Installed files are in `~/.m2/repository/com/isomorphic/smartgwt/lgpl` you can check availability and versions there too.

Answer (score -1):

By design, there is no answer: Maven dependency upgrades are manual.

When appropriate, you can look for new releases of your dependency (in this case SmartGWT), find out what the new version is called in the dependency's public Maven repository, update your project's POM, and update your local repository as necessary (`mvn install` like in the example, deleting old versions, etc.)